# Confused about the layout of this

Tags: sources-mekorot, history, army-military-war, navi-prophets

Joshua 6:12-13 Speaks about the Kohanim, armed men, and rear guard and how they were ordered when they walked with the Aron. Is there a representation of this actually looked, I'm not sure who was in front and who was behind because the words Lifney and Aharei can mean both. Also the Kohanim were holding the Aron and were also behind it? How's it work.

וַיַּשְׁכֵּ֥ם יְהוֹשֻׁ֖עַ בַּבֹּ֑קֶר וַיִּשְׂא֥וּ הַכֹּֽהֲנִ֖ים אֶת־אֲר֥וֹן יְהֹוָֽה:
13And the seven priests bearing the seven trumpets of rams' horns before the Ark of the Lord were going continuously, and they blew with the trumpets; and the armed men went before them; and the rear guard came after the Ark of the Lord, (the priests) going on and blowing with the trumpets.     יג וְשִׁבְעָ֣ה הַכֹּֽהֲנִ֡ים נֹֽשְׂאִים֩ שִׁבְעָ֨ה שֽׁוֹפְר֜וֹת הַיֹּֽבְלִ֗ים לִפְנֵי֙ אֲר֣וֹן יְהֹוָ֔ה הֹֽלְכִ֣ים הָל֔וֹךְ וְתָֽקְע֖וּ בַּשּֽׁוֹפָר֑וֹת וְהֶֽחָלוּץ֙ הֹלֵ֣ךְ לִפְנֵיהֶ֔ם וְהַֽמְאַסֵּ֗ף הֹלֵךְ֙ אַֽחֲרֵי֙ אֲר֣וֹן יְהֹוָ֔ה הָל֖וֹךְ (כתיב הָולֹ֖ךְ) וְתָק֥וֹעַ בַּשּֽׁוֹפָרֽוֹת: